# Getting error when importing some package on python scripts

Tags: python, python-2.6

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./convert.py", line 6, in <module>
    import openpyxl # from https://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/ or PyPI (e.g. via pip)
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

i have installed the python package openpyxl but this error still appear

Im using linux python version 2.6.6
any help please

i got this new error when i ran the python2.7 script.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyErr_ReplaceException
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations? How did you install openpyxl ?

Comment: i think i got installed the python2.7 but it doesnot appear on $ ls /usr/bin/python, i have installed the openpyxl using pip

Comment: try the following - `which python2.7` and `which pip` .

Comment: output was /usr/local/bin/python2.7 and /usr/local/bin/pip i remmember you, thanks for helping again. i got a problem now again, i want to convert my csv file to xlsx file but this hinders me

Comment: Seems like your pip is for python2.7 , so when you install `openpyxl` that way it only gets installed for `python 2.7` not the 2.6.6 version. If you are fine with using `python 2.7` , use `python2.7` in command line to open that version of python

Comment: how can i remove this python2.7 and use 2.6.6 as default would it affect the package i installed?

Comment: Why would you want to use Python 2.6? Python 2.7 is backward compatible with 2.6.

Comment: so how to configure the error above?

Comment: How did you install 2.7.10? I installed from source, and it runs fine for me. Did you install a binary package, or compile and install from source?

Comment: link me with your stuff thanks.. ill reinstall mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openpyxl module has 2 dependent modules : 1. jdcal 2. et_xmlfile

I was able to install openpyxl module and this is what I did :

1.Downloaded the openpyxl,jdcal and et_xmlfile from https://pypi.python.org/pypi and saved jdcal-1.0.tar.gz, et_xmlfile-1.0.0.tar.gz,openpyxl-2.3.0-b2.tar.gz in a local folder in my system.

2.Then I ran the commands in the following order :

```
pip install jdcal-1.0.tar.gz
pip install et_xmlfile-1.0.0.tar.gz
pip install openpyxl-2.3.0-b2.tar.gz
```

openpyxl got successfully after this. Please check whether this helps.